# Audio out of sync when import file cut by ffmpeg with -c copy

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere

I have a lot of clips made with ffmpeg using this command:

`ffmpeg.exe -ss XX:XX -t XX:XX -i original.mp4 -c copy clip.mp4`.

That `copy` option gives a couple seconds of silence in a result clip, but when a sound starts it is perfectly synced and all players I tried can handle it correctly.

But after importing in Adobe Premiere I got audio and video desynchronized, because it removes that silent at the beginning.

I believe that mp4 has some builtin delay and Adobe Premiere ignore it during import, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I have to re-encode the video with `h264` for v and `aac` for audio then it works as expected.